# C++ macro to replace .at() with []

Tags: c++

I often have an index out of bounds error that could easily be caught if I used `.at()` instead of `[]` to access an element in a vector or string. However, `at()` slows down my program by a factor of 5 because of bounds checking.

I am trying to write a macro to replace `.at(someVariable)` with `[someVariable]` this way I can just uncomment the macro instead of replacing each `.at()` with a `[]` manually. I have read the documentation on macros on cppreference.com but can't seem to devise a way to get this functionality.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general I'd avoid this kind of macros, as they are "invisible" (so the altered semantics is subtly hidden from anyone not in the knows) and can alter functionality of code that actually expected `at` to throw on out of bounds, even in release builds. If anything, I'd define something that stands out, for example an all-uppercase `AT`.

Fortunately, this is not actually needed, as the "big three" C++ runtimes already have builtin functionality to conditionally enable boundary checking on `operator[]` (which has also the advantage of being more readable than `at`):

- if you are using g++/libstdc++ if you pass `-​D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` you get [the debug version of STL containers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode.html), which perform boundary checks on `operator[]`, plus a lot of other debug checks on iterators;
- CLang/libc++ can do [similar checks setting `_LIBCPP_DEBUG` to 1](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/DesignDocs/DebugMode.html);
- for Visual C++ [the analogous functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/checked-iterators?view=Vs-2019) is enabled with `ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` set to `2` (and it's already enabled by default in debug builds).

Incidentally, some of these errors (those that actually overflow the allocated size, not just the "logically valid" size of the vector) may also be spotted using the [address sanitizer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (`-fsanitize=address` on gcc and clang) or valgrind (slow!) and similar tools.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way that does not involve macros - it uses c++17's `if constexpr` for ease:

```
#include <vector>

constexpr bool safe_mode = true;  // or false

template<class Container>
auto at(Container& v, std::size_t i) -> decltype(auto)
{
    if constexpr (safe_mode)
        return v.at(i);
    else
        return v[i];
}

int& test(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    return at(v, 6);
}
```

Comment: Why is `decltype(auto)` trailing?

Comment: @CruzJean if you mean why have I chosen to write it that way, probably by force of habit. I write a fair amount of template code and I find it's useful to have all the function's/method's types available to me. So I tend to standardise on trailing return types. Having said that, I see I've mixed styles in the above code. :)

Comment: Ah, I was just curious if there was some subtle difference it made that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: As of a year ago, at the suggestion of one of the head project leads on our application, I've started using the trailing return types predominantly in my code (almost exclusively), and I'm finding them to be much more readable.  That, and combined with "almost always auto", the resulting C++ code parses as much cleaner.  All a matter of opinion, I know.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the full name of the array dereference operator:

```
#define at(x) operator[](x)
```

The `(x)` part isn't essential, but will only replace `at` if it is followed by an argument, rather than replacing the word on its own.  You'll also want to define this *after* including all the standard headers, or it'll replace the `at` member function declarations in classes that have it, resulting in compilation errors.

Comment: Why is it that you don't need a . before at in the macro? Shouldn't it replace the . too?

Comment: @user3586940 You can't replace the `.` in a macro, since a `.` can't be in a macro name.